# How to mock a module's method properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, jestjs

I have a module that looks like this:

```
import {
    Request,
    Response,
    NextFunction,
} from 'express';

export function checkAuthorization (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void {
    if (req.user) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
    }
}
```

I want to mock the method `checkAuthorization`. The test file looks like this:

```
import * as authModule from '../check-authorization';
import { NextFunction } from 'express';

describe('test', () => {

    const checkAuthorizationMock: jest.SpyInstance = jest.spyOn(authModule, 'checkAuthorization');
    checkAuthorizationMock.mockImplementation((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => next());

    it('test case ...', async() => {
    // making HTTP request using **supertest**
    });
});
```

I get ***Unauthorized (code 401)*** as a response when I make the HTTP request in the *it* block, which means the mock doesn't apply. How can I solve this problem and use the mock instead of the real implementation of *checkAuthorization* method?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an explanation, but I solved the problem by mocking the module's method outside of the *describe* block:

```
jest.mock('../check-authorization', () => ({
    checkAuthorization: (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void => {
        next();
    },
}));

describe('test', () => {

});
```

An explanation from someone will be appreciated. Thanks :)